# Azure iOS push notification not working on production mode?

Tags: swift, azure, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I'm using xcode and language as swift for my app.I'm using Azure for push notification.I created two certificates(Production/Sandbox). When i use sandbox certificate notifications are receiving when i use production its not working.
Note: in xcode 8 I have enable Automatically manage signing the provision profile[image]

Any suggestion to over come the issue ?

My code:

//
//  AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var badgeCount:Int = 0


  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        //Push Notification Configs
        NSLog("Push Notification Configured.")
        let notiType:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert ,.Badge , .Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notiType, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        //Push Notification Configs



        let helper = PlistHelper()
        let _webApiHelper = WebApiHelper()

        let isFirstTimeUser = helper.getAnyBooleanValueFromPlistFile("IsFirstTimeUser")

        if(isFirstTimeUser)
        {
            //Mark First Time Login
            helper.addBooleanValueToPlistFile(false, Key: "IsFirstTimeUser")
            //Show WelcomeController
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("welcomeScreenId") as! VideoPlayerViewController
            if let window = self.window {
                window.rootViewController = rootController
            }
        } else{
            //If previously logged in

            let url = _webApiHelper.BaseURL + "api/Account/ValidateUser"
            let token = helper.getTOKENFromPlistFile()
            let headers = [
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                "Accept": "application/json"
            ]

            Alamofire.request(.POST, url,  headers: headers).responseJSON
                { response in

                    if(response.response?.statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        //if IsLoggedIn -> go to home else go to login

                        let IsLoggedIn = helper.getAnyBooleanValueFromPlistFile("hasLoggedIn")

                        if(IsLoggedIn)
                        {
                            NSLog("Previously loggedIn - Go to home")
                            //Go to home
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainController") as! SWRevealViewController
                            if let window = self.window {
                                window.rootViewController = rootController
                            }
                        }else{
                            NSLog("Previously not loggoed in-Go to Login")
                            //Go to Login
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ApploginControllerId") as! AppLoginViewController
                            if let window = self.window {
                                window.rootViewController = rootController
                            }
                        }

                    } else{
                        NSLog("Go to Login")
                        //Go to Login
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ApploginControllerId") as! AppLoginViewController
                        if let window = self.window {
                            window.rootViewController = rootController
                        }

                    }

            }//END - request

        }
        return true
    }

    //Added for APNS
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: ", error.description)
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
    {
        IsValidUser(){ (boolValue) -> () in

            //If registerd user register for push notifications
            if(boolValue)
            {
                NSLog("Registering for push")
                let hub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString:HUBLISTENACCESS, notificationHubPath:HUBNAME)
                hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: nil, completion: { (error) in

                    print("Device Token  \(deviceToken) \n" )
                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        NSLog("Error registering for notification: \(error)")
                    }
                })
            }

        }

    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let dics = userInfo as NSDictionary
         print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
         print("Msg:: \(dics.objectForKey("aps")?.objectForKey("alert"))")
         print("Test:: \(dics.objectForKey("customPayload"))")

        var msgTitle = ""
        var message = ""

        //Message Title
        if let Title = (dics.objectForKey("customPayload")!.objectForKey("Title"))
        {
            msgTitle = Title as! String
        } else
        {
            NSLog("Alert message is Null")
        }
        //Push Message
        if let msg = dics.objectForKey("customPayload")!.objectForKey("Message")
        {
            message = msg as! String
        } else
        {
            NSLog("Alert message is Null")
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReceivedNotification", object:userInfo)


        if application.applicationState == .Active
        {
            MessageBox(msgTitle, message: message as NSString)
        }else{
            //Go to Wall post on notification click.
            let id = dics.objectForKey("customPayload")!.objectForKey("Id") as! Int
            ViewPostInDetailView(id)
        }

    }

    func ViewPostInDetailView(id:Int) -> Void
    {
        let helper = PlistHelper()
        let IsLoggedIn = helper.getAnyBooleanValueFromPlistFile("hasLoggedIn")

        if(IsLoggedIn)
        {
            //Goto Detail post
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostDetail4STBID") as! PostDetailViewController4
            if let window = self.window {
                rootController.PostId = id
                rootController.FromNotification = true
                window.rootViewController = rootController
            }
        }else{
            NSLog("Go to Login - user is not logged in.")
            //Go to Login
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ApploginControllerId") as! AppLoginViewController
            if let window = self.window {
                window.rootViewController = rootController
            }
        }



    }
    func MessageBox(title:NSString,message:NSString){

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title as String , message: message as String, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        NSLog("applicationDidEnterBackground")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
         NSLog("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
//        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        //badgeCount = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber
        //badgeCount = badgeCount + 1;
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    //check is valid user by token
    func IsValidUser( completion: (result: Bool)->()) {

        let _webHelper = WebApiHelper()

        let url_ValidateUser = _webHelper.BaseURL + "api/Account/ValidateUser"
        let _plist = PlistHelper()
        let token = _plist.getTOKENFromPlistFile()
        let headers = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]


        Alamofire.request(.POST, url_ValidateUser,  headers: headers).responseJSON
            { response in

                if(response.response?.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    completion(result: true)

                } else{
                    completion(result: false)
                }

        }//END - request
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have setup the server side correctly? You have to upload your production certificate as well.

Comment: @EricAya I think code is working fine because it's working for Sandbox mode. But I'll show the code.

Comment: @ThomasG. Yes I have upload the .p12 file for sandbox mode which is working when i upload the production .p12 file which was not working(not getting notifications).

Comment: Do you using SBNotificationHub to register to the endpoint? If so check your connectionString and notificationHubPath.

Comment: @ThomasG.Yes I'm using correct notificationHubPath & connectionString

Comment: Please post the logs from the console. Get´s "Registering for push" logged or "Failed to register for remote notifications:"

Comment: @ThomasG. As logs i'm getting no errors for registration for push.
Im getting this device token
Device Token  <2d17c487 d2aa55eb c02fc3b4 ac402e79 804a654f b7d86598 9465dc85 b0d03ee6>

Comment: Guys is this a problem with the xcode automatically managed signing ??.